# Random div ,help me please

Tags: javascript, html, css

This code functions right, it displays 5 random images with corresponding text.My problem is that I would like to separate the text into another div so that I can put another function to it ,but still i want the images in random with its corresponding  text.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".Image").hide();

    var elements = $(".Image");
    var elementCount = elements.size();
    var elementsToShow = 5;
    var alreadyChoosen = ",";
    var i = 0;
    while (i < elementsToShow) {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * elementCount);
        if (alreadyChoosen.indexOf("," + rand + ",") < 0) {
            alreadyChoosen += rand + ",";
            elements.eq(rand).show();
            ++i;
        }
    }
});

/*]]>*/
</script>

<div class="Image"><img   src="image1"/><text id="id1">1</text></div>
<div class="Image"><img   src="image2"/><text id="id2">2</text></div>
<div class="Image"><img   src="image3"/><text id="id3">3</text></div>
<div class="Image"><img   src="image4"/><text id="id4">4</text></div>
<div class="Image"><img   src="image5"/><text id="id5">5</text></div>
<div class="Image"><img   src="image6"/><text id="id6">6</text></div>
<div class="Image"><img   src="image7"/><text id="id7">7</text></div>
<div class="Image"><img   src="image8"/><text id="id8">8</text></div>
```

Comment: Those `<text>` tags are invalid.

Comment: @techfoobar but it's working for me. anyway all I want to do is to put the text into another div.

Comment: You mean `<div><img ><div><text>1</text></div></div>`?

Comment: You could use the image index to refer to the index of the text element node list.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you are violating a lot of best practices. `text` is not a valid tag. Is there any reason to separate the text in another div? Is there any reason to show all the elements, hide them and than show only 5 randomly(You could directly show randomly only 5)?

However, you could solve it like this:

```
<div class="image image1"><img src="image1"/></div>
<div class="text text1"><text id="id1">1</text></div>

<div class="image image2"><img src="image2"/></div>
<div class="text text2"><text id="id2">2</text></div>
```

and than on JS, hide both images and texts:

```
$(".image").hide();
$(".text").hide();
```

and than instead of `elements.eq(rand).show();` you can select based on the id:

```
$(".image"+(rand+1)).show(); // rand+1 because rand can be [0,8) in your case
$(".text"+(rand+1)).show();
```

Or, its better if you can wrap the elements that will always be together in one div as a wrapper.

Comment: HTML5 in the future may allow custom elements. http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/

Comment: @Mouser It already does, see Angular's directives, for example.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps

```html
<div class="Image"><img width="200" height="200"  src="1.jpg"/><div id="id1">1</text></div>
<div class="Image"><img width="200" height="200"    src="2.jpg"/><div id="id2">2</text></div>
<div class="Image"><img width="200" height="200"    src="3.jpg"/><div id="id3">3</text></div>
<div class="Image"><img width="200" height="200"    src="4.jpg"/><div id="id4">4</text></div>
<div class="Image"><img width="200" height="200"    src="5.jpg"/><div id="id5">5</text></div>
<div class="Image"><img width="200" height="200"    src="6.jpg"/><div id="id6">6</text></div>
<div class="Image"><img width="200" height="200"    src="7.jpg"/><div id="id7">7</text></div>
<div class="Image"><img width="200" height="200"    src="8.jpg"/><div id="id8">8</text></div>
```